# Node.js Writable Stream creates wrong files (larger and unreadable)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am writing a piece of code to send files in chunks from Angular.js client to Node.js server through Socket.io. The client slices a file in chunks and emits them via Socket.io to the server.

The file is read on the client using javascript's `FileReader`:

```
var chunkSize = 524288, // 0.5mb
    reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
    // ok, this one is very simplified so that I don't have to copy
    // all of my code here, but basically I send files with an offset
    // like:
    // file.data.substr(offset, Math.min(chunkSize, file.size - offset));
    // for testing purposes I use a file smaller than 0.5mb, so it
    // gets sent in one chunk
    var chunk = e.target.result.substr(0, chunkSize);   

    // this one is also simplified, I use unique file ids to write to
    // a certain file

    // during testing I use a file of 48014 bytes, if I console.log()
    // it, it says that chunk.length is 48014 bytes
    socket.emit('fileUpload', { chunk: chunk });
};

reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

Then this event reaches the server:

```
// this one is also simplified, in fact I use three events, not one:
// fileUploadStart, fileUpload and fileUploadEnd, but for the sake of
// this question it's irrelevant

socket.on('fileUpload', function(data) {
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream(data.id + '.tmp'));
    stream.on('drain', function() {
        socket.emit('streamDrained', { description: 'Stream drained.', size: stream.bytesWritten });
    });
    stream.write(data.chunk);
});
```

And then on the client I get `streamDrained` event, which tells me that 69127 bytes were written instead of 48014 (which was the size of the original file). If I inspect the resulting file, it is also 69127 bytes, and it is corrupted. The original file was `.pdf`, the resulting file can be opened with a PDF-reader, it has same number of pages as the original, but they are all blank.

Besides, if I `console.log()` the length of the chunk received by the server, it is also 48014 bytes in length, but after the stream is written, the file turns out to be 69127 bytes.

Seems like I'm missing something either in the concept of `FileReader`, or in `Writable Stream`, or in `Socket.io`, or in any combination of it. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely what is happening here is that you're converting binary data to a UTF-8 string which is likely to result in extra bytes (invalid replacement character bytes) when invalid UTF-8 character sequences are found in the binary data.

To transfer binary data in socket.io 1.x, you need to make sure that `chunk` is either a `Blob`, `ArrayBuffer`, or `File` instance. Then on the node side, `data.chunk` should be a `Buffer` containing the same binary data.

One example solution would be to use [`reader.readAsArrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) instead of `reader.readAsBinaryString()`. It should also be noted that [`reader.readAsBinaryString()` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString).

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I used `.readAsArrayBuffer()` and had to change `.subst()` to `.slice()`, other than that everything is working perfectly!