# Writing chunks to writable steam produces incorrect file - currupt and in larger size than original file

Tags: node.js, typescript, stream

I want to download a file from the server, we have a C# service which returns chunks of data of the file as requested in the input (HTTP status - 206). At the client, in the Node.js app, I want to combine all the chunks and save the file.

I can successfully download a text file, it matches the file on the server. However, when I try to download a PDF file. The resultant file is almost twice the size of the original file and it is corrupted - I download individual chunks - combine them using writable stream.

I have tried to create writable stream specifying encoding as utf8 (results in larger file), binary and ASCII (results in smaller files).

I can't create a readable stream and pipe it to writable stream as the source data (chunk) is already present in the form of API response and readable stream only accept file path as the input. Is it correct?

I have gone through the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218913/node-js-writable-stream-creates-wrong-files-larger-and-unreadable), but it is not much helpful.

```
private async WriteToStreamAsyc(wStream: Writable, chunk: any) {
    !await wStream.write(chunk);
}
```

I know this is a very trivial case, people may be widely doing this task, However, I am out of luck and options, any suggestions could be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using node request library. Request library has the default encoding of utf8, hence it converts the response buffer into string, which results in larger files and especial characters cant be recognized which results in corrupt files. By specifying the encoding as null we can get the original buffer.

> encoding - encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. If
>   null, the body is returned as a Buffer. Anything else (including the
>   default value of undefined) will be passed as the encoding parameter
>   to toString() (meaning this is effectively utf8 by default). (Note: if
>   you expect binary data, you should set encoding: null.)